# Website platform listing in facebook app center

Tags: facebook

I am trying to list a website with facebook login to App center. The option appears but its grayed out and cannot select the "on switch"

Although I added the Website platform under  Settings, and also filled out the URL, I cannot check the platform as website in App Details page. I can do that for Website-mobile though.

I get this notice "This platform cannot be listed because it is either configured incorrectly or not supported in App Center."

I tried searching online and on this site with no luck. The only response was to make sure the URL is populated in app settings and that is already done with no avail.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have selected "Games" as category in the app details --> Category section, try to change it to something else.

Worked for me.